# How to store JSON objects in SQLite on Android

Tags: java, json, sqlite

This is my SQLite code

```
public class CategoryHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "category.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbcategory";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "_name";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "_age";
    // private static final String EMAIL = "_email";
    private static final String GENDER = "_gender";

    /*
     * private static final String email = "email"; private static final String
     * gender = "gender";
     */

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441031/want-to-insert-json-data-into-the-sqlite-database

    Category openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public CategoryHelper(Context context) {
        openHelper = new Category(context);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void saveCategoryRecord(String id, String name, String age,
            String gender) {
        try {

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
            contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
            // contentValues.put(EMAIL,m.getEmail());

            contentValues.put(GENDER, gender);

            database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("problem", e + "");
        }
    }

    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }

    private class Category extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public Category(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_AGE + " TEXT + )");
            Log.d("name", TABLE_NAME.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main activity

```
    @Override
    protected List<getsetclass> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {


            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://infograins.com/INFO01/socialpad/api.php?action=searchuser&userid=109&lat=22.6858623&long=75.8597824");

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("Searchuser");//get json array
                //Log.e("jarray", jarray.toString());

                  List<getsetclass> mpojo = new Vector<getsetclass>();// put getset class into listview 
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {//convert one by one and stored in json object 
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                     String email = object.getString("email");//get json object
                     //Log.w("email",email.toString());
                     String name = object.getString("fullname");
                     Log.e("name",name.toString());

                     String gender = object.getString("gender");
                     //Log.e("gender",gender.toString());
                     String age = object.getString("age");
                   //  Log.e("age",age.toString());
                     String id=object.getString("userid");
                    String image=object.getString("image1");
                   Log.w("image", image.toString());
                   Log.d("bhjs--+______________------_-_","jgfjgfsjfs");




                     getsetclass m=new getsetclass(email, gender, name, age, image, id);
                     m.setAge(age);
                     m.setGender(gender);
                     m.setFullname(name);
                     m.setEmail(email);
                     m.setId(id);
                     m.setImage(image);
                     database.saveCategoryRecord(id,name,age,gender);
                        gs.add(m);}
                return mpojo;

            }
```

I am constantly receiving these errors in logcat, but I don't understand what is happening

```
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteLog(5395): (1) table tbcategory has no column named _gender
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteDatabase(5395): Error inserting _name=Apeksha Sharma _id=94 _age=23 _gender=Female
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteDatabase(5395): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tbcategory has no column named _gender (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tbcategory(_name,_id,_age,_gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteDatabase(5395):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteDatabase(5395):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
11-03 07:48:41.848: E/SQLiteDatabase(5395):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
```

Comment: did you change the database without increasing the database version?

Comment: I solved these error but json data does not stored in sqlite....Everything is gone fine there is no error in log cat but data does not stored in my DBMS package name...Can any one help me??