# Error Parsing JSON Data - Asynchronous Task

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-asynctask

I am getting the error `Error parsing Data` which I have caught in the main exception when parsing JSON Data.

However - my error `No Data Found` is not being caught in the `JSONException`, which makes me think that the database is being read successfully,

I have a php file on my server:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("database_ip","database_username","database_password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");

$sql=mysql_query("select * from table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));// this will print the output in json

mysql_close();
?>
```

Navigating the to the php file online shows the JSON data as expected:

`[{"KEY_ROWID":"1","KEY_NAME":"Andrew","KEY_SCORE":"100","KEY_DATE":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"KEY_ROWID":"2","KEY_NAME":"Peter","KEY_SCORE":"5000","KEY_DATE":"2013-11-29 10:58:21"}]`

In Android, I use an `Async` task to read the data:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url_select = "http://mywebsite.com/myphpfile.php";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            try {

                JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    // get an output on the screen
                    String name = Jasonobject.getString("KEY_NAME");
                    text.append(name + "\n");

                }

            }

            catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO Data Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        }

    }
```

In my activites `onCreate` I instantiate the Async Class:

```
new Task().execute();
```

Any suggestions on why there is an error parsing data?

Thanks

Note : outputting the variable 'result' with println () outputs the Json to the logcat as expected

Comment: **Side note:** `mysql_*` functions are ***deprecated***, use `mysqli_*` ones instead.

Comment: what you are getting in `result` from webservice ?

Comment: what's printed after your "Error parsing data " Log

Comment: just write/check in doInBackground: `Log.d("log_tag", result);`

Comment: It's can be that the **TextView** is not found, you're catching all **Exception** in the second "catch"

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK result outputs the correct `JSON` data.

Comment: @MaximShoustin this log returns the correct `JSON` data

Comment: Could you paste your json here ? It would be really helpful to debug

Comment: @Rahul Gupta I have posted json in main question.  But here it is:[{"KEY_ROWID":"1","KEY_NAME":"Andrew","KEY_SCORE":"100","KEY_DATE":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"KEY_ROWID":"2","KEY_NAME":"Peter","KEY_SCORE":"5000","KEY_DATE":"2013-11-29 10:58:21"}]  Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Form your code:

```
...
catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```

The problem is that it might be not Json exception but **any** Exception. In practice it is not recommended to catch type `Exception`. We should only catch specific subtypes of the Exception class. In our case `findViewById` throws : `NullPointerException`. So first of all change it to `NullPointerException` (in additional to JSONException) and run program again.

I would change `Error parsing data` to something generic.

Suppose we don't have Exception on `findViewById` and our `text` is not `null`.

Try to use `Handler` to update main thread (aka GUI):

```
private Handler mHandler = null;

 ...

 mHandler = new Handler();

 ... 

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // get an output on the screen
                        String name = Jasonobject.getString("KEY_NAME");
                        text.append(name + "\n");
                    }
                }

                catch (JSONException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO Data Found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error  " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, 100); // dummy delay
```

*As a side note*:

The row `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` put outside of the loop `for`

Comment: I removed the main `Exception` and the application crashes. I will try your `handler` suggestion later - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Dud i pasted your json in a local file in assets folder and tried to retrieve it. It is working fine. Here is my code. I cannot use your code because the url will not work from my side . Anyways, here is my code :-

```
    package com.example.test;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    String jsonString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Making HTTP request
        // String url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ir?format=json";
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/andApp/artikel.php";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        // JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        // JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl1(url);
        // JSONObject json = null;
        JSONArray json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("json1.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

            // json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            json = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        try {
            JSONArray json2 = json;
            // .getJSONArray("artikel");

            for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = json2.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                String name = c.optString("KEY_ROWID", "");
                String capitalCity = c.optString("KEY_NAME", "");
                String score = c.optString("KEY_SCORE", "");
                String date = c.optString("KEY_DATE", "");

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks dude, I will try this later tonight, or tomorrow, 6pm Friday Local time here :)

Comment: I get an error at `JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();` I tried to find an example of this class at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202304/jsonparser-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type  Should I be following that? Or possibly this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ . Thanks for any help.

Comment: Dude listen, that is a class for parsing json from url. Whichever method you are using, DEBUG your code line by line and see if it is working. You should debug your code.