# How to make a JSONObject using JSONParser class method

Tags: java, json

Not sure if my title quite suits my problem, but that's the best I could come up with.

This is my JSONString from a website:

```
{"0":{"productname":"Varios - NEUTROGENA PROTECTOR LABIAL SPF5","imageurl":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41cm5BHMGtL._SL160_.jpg","producturl":"","price":"1.72","currency":"GBP","saleprice":"","storename":"N/A"}}
```

I want to make a JSONObject with the class provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202304/jsonparser-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type).

This is what I have done so far:

```
JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser(); 
String jsonString = null;
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(url, GET, params);
```

The *makeHttpRequest* method accepts 3 arguments:

1. the URL - where I put the URL of the website that gives me the JSONResponse from above;
2. the String(GET or POST);
3. `List<NameValuePair>`

I don't know what should I put in the list to make my method work. In which format do I have to put it in the List to make the method return a propper JSONObject which would be good for later (easy) use.

Comment: I expect it can be left empty (null?) because you are not sending any extra params. Not sure how it fits your use-case but in general I suggest using https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the question in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202304/jsonparser-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type), it is followed from [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/), and according to that tutorial, the list is used to pass the list of params if necessary to the httprequest using the `org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair` class. The `NameValuePair` itself is an interface and its documentation is given in [this link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/class-use/NameValuePair.html)

You could add values to the params list as shown below. Taken from the tutorial:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
```

So you just have to pass the params that you need to the URL by changing the key-value pairs added to the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've seen the tutorial posted there, but my question is how to add the e.g. "name"(the 2nd parameter) in your example, when I don't know the name yet.
The "name" in the tutorial is already known, like this: `String name = txtName.getText().toString();`

Comment: those are not the values you would receive in the json, they are merely the values you might want to send to the server for the server to respond correctly, like the values you would fill in a form when you submit them. They are basically the values that come up after the `?` in a get http request. you can google to learn about urls and params