# Cannot resolve JSONParser

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, jsonparser

I am  working on selenium webdriver, I have created a JSON file but when I am reading data from that file using JSONParser, eclipse shows error "JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type"
The screenshot is  [image]

my code is as given -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import ru.sbtqa.tag.parsers.JsonParser; 


public class First {


 static void user_auth()throws JSONException
{
        Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in) ;
        String username , password ;
        System.out.println ("Enter username(reg. no.):-");
        username = in.next();
        System.out.println (" Enter password:-");
        password = in.next();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject() ;
        obj.put("USERNAME" ,username  ) ;
        obj.put("PASSWORD" ,password  ) ;
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("data.json"))
        {
            file.write(obj.toString());
        }
        catch ( IOException ex )
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


}
public static void main ( String args [ ] )
{
    // checking if the file exists or not 
    // If it is first time 
    File f = new File("./data.json");
    if(f.exists() == false && f.isDirectory()== false ) { 
        System.out.println("It's your first time...");
        user_auth();
    }


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String url = "http://14.139.108.229/W27/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fw27%2fMyInfo%2fw27MyInfo.aspx" ;
    driver.get(url);
    int attempt = 2 ;

    while ( attempt > 0  )
    {
            if ( attempt != 2 )
                user_auth();
            String name , password ;
            try
            {
                FileReader file = new FileReader ( "data.json") ;
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser (file);
                Object obj = new Object (parser) ;
                JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) obj ;
                name = (String)jsonobj.get("USERNAME");
                password = (String)jsonobj.get("PASSWORD");
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
            catch(IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
            catch(ParseException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
            catch(Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"txtUserName\"]")).sendKeys(name);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password1\"]")).sendKeys(password);
            WebElement button =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Submit1\"]"));
            button.click();
            if ( driver.getCurrentUrl() == url )
            {
                attempt -- ;
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"txtUserName\\\"]")).clear();
                try
                {
                    FileReader file = new FileReader ( "data.json") ;
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser (file);
                    Object obj = new Object (parser) ;
                    JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) obj ;
                    jsonobj .remove(jsonobj.toString());
                    if ( attempt == 0 )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Wrong UserName or Password");
                        driver.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    System.out.println("ry Re-Login");

                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
                catch(IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
                catch(ParseException e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
                catch(Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            else break ;
    }

}
```

}

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202304/jsonparser-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964369/how-to-make-a-jsonobject-using-jsonparser-class-method?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but this does not solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are missing a dependency json-simple.

**1) Here is the link [JSON.simple » 1.1.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) where you can download missing dependency.**

**2) Add downloaded dependency** 
[image]
[image]

**3) If you have the maven or gradle project then copy dependencies line.**
[image]

**4) Then clean build the project and see the magic.**

Comment: I have downloaded the  jar which you mentioned and imported in the project but still, when I am using JSONParser it shows "The constructor JSONParser() is deprecated"

Comment: I don't how to add Screenshot her.

Comment: Please help me this project is quite important for me !!

Comment: I've added a new answer which can help you to improve your understanding of fetching JSON data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here As you're facing an error like; JSONParser it shows "The constructor JSONParser() is deprecated" because You've not used it correctly to get your JSON file data I've posted below sample code where you can get the idea.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(new FileReader("L:/data.json"));
            String name = (String) obj.get("USERNAME");
            String password = (String) obj.get("PASSWORD");
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

note: Here I've used the same "json-simple-1.1.1.jar" file.

> File: data.json

```
{
      "USERNAME": "abc",
      "PASSWORD": "xyz"
}
```