# Cannot resolve symbol JSONParser

Tags: java, android, json

So I have imported `import org.json.*` and It doesnt seem to recognize JSONParser.

```
String filePath = "C://CN//jokes.json";
 try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

jokes.json has the same information as http://api.icndb.com/jokes I want to be able to get the data from that site, but to test I have created a file. This is my first time using Json so I'm a bit clueless. I have updated the jdk and jre, but I still have the same issue. Here is a screenshot showing how it looks:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DQcx.png) I have also read a similar post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202304/jsonparser-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type?rq=1), but it is different from my problem.

If you look at the screenshot it seems `import org.json.*` doesnt have class JSONParser. I have also tried adding `import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;` but it doesnt recognize it. because "simple" doesnt exist

Answer (score 18):

For Android Studio, just add this to the build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
```

For other IDEs and other options, see here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1

Comment: Thanks, this is a better solution but i am getting `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1` when I compile and run it, any solution on this?

Comment: Yea, I did remove it from libs folder on the android project, still same issue

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is a bit out-dated. ( At the end of 2018 compile will be either api or implementation also there is a new version 1.1.1 )

Add this to the build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
```

and then import

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Hope it helps as it does to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and hope this might help somebody.

Add this to the build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```